# Why are relations between databases not part of the migration file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I use the migration file to setup the database structure.
That is very convenient as I am not constrained to a specific type of database (mysql, sql,...)

If I want to have relationships between different tables, I have to use the Associations has_to, belongs_to **IN THE MODEL FILE**.

I don't get this. Now you can't just roll back a migration of the database go on from this point. No, you also have to modify the model file manually.

Why did they choose this design concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations are for changing the state of your database, not for altering the behavior of your models.

> I don't get this. Now you can't just roll back a migration of the database go on from this point. No, you also have to modify the model file manually.

Of course you do. You have to modify the model/controller/view code to use *any* migrated changes to the database, associations or otherwise. What's the big deal? How else would you *consume* the changes you're making to your database, if not through changes to your application code?

Your application code is *always* going to be tied to the state of the database. Migrations aren't supposed to isolate you from this.

Comment: But why didn't they shift the relationship code (belongs_to, has_many,...) to the migration file. That it would be "cleaner"?

Comment: If that's the case, how would you handle polymorphic associations? You have to be able to specify the id and type of the model in those. What about having multiple models post to the same table? What then?

Comment: @Theo No, that would make no sense. The associations between models belong in the models. Migrations run once, introduce change, and then are never run again. They are typically deleted when there is no longer any chance of them being rolled back.